# What is prepended to the front of a ScriptSig and ScriptPubKey of a P2PKH transction?

Tags: raw-transaction, p2pkh, input-script, serialization

In some educational materials on bitcoin P2PKH transactions, I'll see 2 digits included in the front of what would be considered the ScriptSig. For example, what is the `8b` in the front of the ScriptSig below representing?

```
8b483045022100a8205f5879952c6a931affae66519c4a4bda0d912dd166d89e7b671efddfd01e022071a6cf9f3f72c61395ea98c5b23606b9a7d4d5aac97b84a3622beeded49ee40a014104f6209daa9543327eb5b7b2ac0b63089af69abad5b14f4b6cfec5c18279848fa214933decd49c1ca1efe03af8f44b5584b1af8eae6a31a95921bba07e5bf78f90
```

The same with the format of the ScriptPubKey...what is the `19` representing in the front of the ScriptPubKey below?

```
1976a914b58515a69527c806fd404d3d4aa490d56692310b88ac
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the serialization format, the input and output script are introduced by announcing the length of the script.

So that `0x19` indicates that the length of the scriptPubKey is `76a914b58515a69527c806fd404d3d4aa490d56692310b88ac` is 25 bytes, and `0x8b` indicates that `483045022100a8205f5879952c6a931affae66519c4a4bda0d912dd166d89e7b671efddfd01e022071a6cf9f3f72c61395ea98c5b23606b9a7d4d5aac97b84a3622beeded49ee40a014104f6209daa9543327eb5b7b2ac0b63089af69abad5b14f4b6cfec5c18279848fa214933decd49c1ca1efe03af8f44b5584b1af8eae6a31a95921bba07e5bf78f90` is a 139 bytes.